# Passing data from controller to JavaScript in GSP

Tags: javascript, json, grails

I want to pass data from controller to javascript by embedded data directly in view. (So there won't be additional requests.)

My first solution is to use `as JSON` in GSP like this:

```
<script>
  var data = ${invoice as JSON};
</script>
```

I don't think it's good idea since I have to use (Grails 2.2)

```
grails.views.default.codec = "none"
```

or (Grails 2.3)

```
grails {
  views {
    gsp {
      codecs {
        expression = 'none'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now, I found that I can create little taglib like this:

```
def json = { attrs, body ->
  out << (attrs.model as JSON)
}
```

And I can use following code in GSP:

```
<script>
  var data = <g:json model="${invoice}" />;
</script>
```

Now, the question. Is using taglib is best practice? If not, please give me the best solution.

Comment: How about sending the json String from the controller to the view, and using `${json.encodeAsJavaScript()}`?

Comment: encodeAsJavaScript() gives me: `var data = \u007b\u0022key1\u0022:\u0022val1\u0022\u002c\u0022key2\u0022:3.14\u007d`

Comment: Oh right, in this case you need the raw data. `${raw(json)}`

Comment: ${raw(json)} works! However `json` have to be String, not JSON object.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transforming the comment in answer. You can create your JSON String in the controller and pass it to the view. Grails 2.3.x have the raw codec that don't encode your content. More info about this codec [here](http://mrhaki.blogspot.ie/2013/11/grails-goodness-generating-raw-output.html).

Example:

```
class MyController {
  def index() {
    String invoiceString = invoice as JSON
    [json: invoiceString]
  }
}
```

*index.gsp*

```
<script>
  var data = ${raw(json)};
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

using grails 2.4.4.

Above answer did not worked for me.

so adding what worked for me.

Source:
http://aruizca.com/how-to-render-json-properly-without-escaping-quotes-inside-a-gsp-script-tag/

```
<g:applyCodec encodeAs="none">
    var data = ${data};
</g:applyCodec>
```

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me on Grails 3.1.4

Answer (score 2):

Now, I'm upgrading to Grails 3.2.4. I found that Sérgio Michels' method is still work. Just make sure `jsonString` is a `String` object.

```
<script>
  var data = ${raw(jsonString)};
</script>
```

If it is not a `String` object, you can use something like following code.

```
<script>
  var data = ${raw(mapInstance.encodeAsJSON().toString)};
</script>
```

Comment: This was why mine wasn't working! My method declared that I was returning a def object. Thank you!